# sprite_sheet system in python and pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Hello guys I come to you again in need of help. Today I was working with sprites and making a system that will chop a sprite sheet up and put all the slices in a list with python and pygame. The problem comes when I want to pass that list into a sprite class to update it and take in player movement. when I try and run my code in idel it tells me,

```
slef.image = sprites[frame]
    TypeError: 'Group' object does not support indexing
```

and I don't know how I can get this running properly.

Here is the system I use to chop the sprite sheet up:

```
class sprite_system(object):
    def slice_sheet(self,sprite_sheet,sprite_start_x,sprite_start_y,sprite_size_x,sprite_size_y,sheet_frames):
        frame = []
        sheet_start = 1 
        frame_pos = 0
        sprite_start_x_base = sprite_size_x
        while sheet_start <= sheet_frames:
            sheet = sprite_sheet
            sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(sprite_start_x,sprite_start_y,sprite_size_x,sprite_size_y))
            sprite_clip = sheet.subsurface(sheet.get_clip())
            frame.append(sprite_clip)
            sprite_start_x += sprite_start_x_base
            sheet_start += 1
        return frame
```

Here is the system I use to make and update the sprite:

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self,sprites,*groups):
        super(player,self).__init__(*groups)
        frame = 0
        slef.image = sprites[frame]
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320,240),sprites.get_size())
    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 10
            frame += 1 
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 10
            frame += 1
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= 10
            frame += 1 
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += 10
            frame += 1 
        if frame > 3:
            frame = 0
```

And finally the main game loop I use to put all of this together:

```
class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):

        sprite = pygame.image.load('test.png')
        image =  sprite_system().slice_sheet(sprite,0,0,64,64,4)
        sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player(sprites)
        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))

            sprites.update()
            sprites.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    Game().main(screen)
```

I hope this is all enough to get some help and if you need to know anything else id be happy to help thanks 
~Eddy

Comment: See also this spritesheet animation demo: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet?parent=CookBook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change some names, because you are using `sprites` an `frames` for the same thing. Also you have the word `slef` instead of `self`.

I propose the following:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, frames, *groups):
        super(player,self).__init__(*groups)
        frame = 0
        self.image = frames[frame]
        ...


class Game(object):

    def main(self, screen):
        sprite = pygame.image.load('test.png')
        frames = sprite_system().slice_sheet(sprite,0,0,64,64,4)
        sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(frames, sprites)
        ...
```

Notes:

- Changed `player` class to capital P `Player` (standard for Python classes)
- Changed the first player argument to frames
- Changed the variable that receives the slice_sheet to `frames`
- Added `frames` to the `Player` creation.

**Update**

Regarding to the commment, you should keep the frames collection as a player attribute, so you can change the frame in update() method:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, frames, *groups):
        super(player,self).__init__(*groups)
        self.frame = 0
        self.frames = frames
        ...

    def update(self):
        ...  # code to select the current frame

        self.frame = frame
        self.image = self.frames[self.frame]
```

Comment: this all worked but when i want to loop through my images it will only play the first frame. i think this is because frame is resenting to 0 every time it is called but i don't know any other way of doing it any tips?